# Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I have a problem with using Hibernate Spatial and PostGIS. I have an entity with a field like this:

```
public class LocationBean {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
  private Point location;
}
```

The problem I have is that I can't load any of these entities from the database, unless location is null for that entity. If it is not null, I get the following error:

```
Exception: Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject
javax.el.ELException: /protected/topPanel/searchBar.xhtml @27,57 completeMethod="#{toppanelbb.completeSearchBar}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoComplete.broadcast(AutoComplete.java:337)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:253)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject
at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PGGeometryValueExtractor.toJTS(PGGeometryValueExtractor.java:113)
at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.AbstractJTSGeometryValueExtractor.doExtract(AbstractJTSGeometryValueExtractor.java:50)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1695)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1627)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1514)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:725)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.QueryWrapper.getResultList(QueryWrapper.java:84)
at com.dobe.app.backingbeans.TopPanelBackingBean.completeSearchBar(TopPanelBackingBean.java:289)
at com.dobe.app.backingbeans.TopPanelBackingBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.completeSearchBar(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
... 45 more
```

The weird thing is that I can persist them just fine, but not load them. For example, if I do something like:

```
LocationBean loc = new LocationBean();
loc.setLocation(new GeometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(lon, lat));
// persist to db...
```

The point is correctly stored correctly in the Postgresql database and querying it works. Only when I load it, it doesn't work.

I can also load other fields from the class, besides the location field. So for instance:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT l.id from LocationBean l  WHERE within(v.location, :filter) = true", Long.class);
```

would work, but:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT l from LocationBean l  WHERE within(v.location, :filter) = true", LocationBean.class);
```

would not.

These are the dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>4.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1002.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas what I could try? I have a workaround solution at the moment, where I only use the persisted GeometryType for querying, but don't ever load it into a java object, but I am not happy with that solution. Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing similar error randomly.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem.
I'm using the following:

1. Tomcat 8.0.3
2. Hibernate version 4.3.6 with Hibernate Spatial
3. Tomcat's JDBC Connection Pool

That error happens because of the way the classes are loaded.
You probably have the postgres driver jar in the tomcat lib folder and the postgis jar in the application's WEB-INF/lib folder.
You have to place both jar files in the same place and only in that place.

If you get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert object of type org.postgis.PGgeometry

...you have the jar's in both locations (tomcat lib and WEB-INF/lib). This was the problem I had. Just make sure the jars won't go to the WEB_INF/lib folder.

Comment: This fixed it for us! Thanks!